# I compile vim9 by my self, but [esc][?4m keeps showing up，why?how to fix this?

Tags: vim, compilation

my configure armument is

```
./configure --with-features=huge --enable-multibyte --enable-python3interp=dynamic --enable-cscope --enable-gui=auto --enable-gtk2-check --enable-fontset --enable-largefile --disable-netbeans --with-compiledby="xxx" --enable-fail-if-missing --prefix=/root/software
make
make install
```

when I edit a new buffer in vim, [esc][?4m appears, how do I fix this problem?

[image: 1]

I recompile vim many times, it does't work, I want [esc][?4m don't show up again.

Comment: Do you have that string appear without any config: `$ vim -Nu NONE`? With the default config: `$ vim --clean`? Where does it appear?

Comment: I tried `$ vim -Nu NONE`，it still appear(many times only one time appear)，it appear at end of my editing. I tried `$ vim --clean`, it didn't apear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just went into the exact same problem today. The fix is adding below lines in your `.vimrc` file:

```
set keyprotocol=
let &term=&term
```

For more information, you can refer to the [issue reported in GitHub](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11728).

Comment: thank you! I used vim 8.2 to fix this problem。 I will try this!

Comment: it worked,can you explain why?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is related with control seqence that your terminal does not support. I'm no expert in Vim, it is beyond my knowledge. You can check the GitHub link if you are interested.